# Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, codeigniter

I am using this code to insert

```
$last_id = "SELECT max(id) as id from clients ";
    $client_id = $this->db->query($last_id)->row();
    $client_last = $client_id->id;
    $data = array();    
for($i=0; $i<count($res); $i++)
{
$data['user_id'] = $res[$i];
$data['client_id']=$client_last;
$this->db->insert("notifications", $data);
}
```

Array `$res` returns values `user_ids` like below:

```
 Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 5
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 6
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 7
    )

)
```

And variable `$client_last` returns single value like `5` or `90` something like this.

In this scenario I want to insert three rows in table notifications inserting the value of `$res` array and same value of `$client_last` against each value of `$res array`.
But in this case I am getting data base error saying:

> Message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

and when I print last query with `$this->db->last_qery();`
It shows something like this

```
INSERT INTO `notifications` (`user_id`, `client_id`) VALUES (, '90')
```

with saying sql error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that your problem is in this line:

```
$data['user_id'] = $res[$i];
```

You should change it to:

```
  $data['user_id'] = $res[$i]->id;
```

Because the id's values are in the object stored in the array `$res`

The code:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($res); $i++)
{
  $data['user_id'] = $res[$i]->id;
  $data['client_id'] = $client_last;
  $this->db->insert("notifications", $data);
}
```